# Lexical analyzer unable to recognize reserved words

Tags: python, lexical-analysis

I'm trying to develop a lexical analyzer which should tokenize and identify operators, identifiers, constants, reserved words, and data types in a code from an external text file, but the problem is I can't get it to identify *reserved words* or *data types*, it considers them as *identifiers* instead. I understand that this is because it matches the very first regex, but I still can't think of another way which will recognize both identifiers/variables as well as reserved words. Any ideas?

```
import re                                 

tokens = []                               
sample_code = open("book.txt","r").read().split()


for word in sample_code:

   
    if re.match("[a-zA-Z]+", word):
        tokens.append([word,'is an Identifier'])

    
    elif re.match("([1-9][0-9]*)|0", word):
        if word[len(word) - 1] == ';': 
            tokens.append([word[:-1], "is Num Constant"])
            tokens.append([';', 'is a Semi-colon'])
        else: 
            tokens.append([word, "is a Num Constant"])
    
    
    elif word in ['str', 'int', 'bool','float','char']: 
        tokens.append([word, 'is a Datatype'])
    

    elif word in '><!*-/+%=':
        tokens.append([word, "is an Operator"])
    

    elif word in ['if','for','break','elif','else','while','then','call','do',
    'endwhile', 'return','void','static','case','throw','private', 'public']:
        tokens.append([word, "is a Reserved Word"])
    
    
print(tokens, '\n')
```

`

Comment: well, it's matching on that regex in the first `if` statement, so it thinks they're identifiers

Comment: yeah that's the issue, i need that regex for identifiers, so what do i do?

Comment: You might consider learning how to use a parser generator such as ANTLR. It is much more efficient to let the tool write the code for you. You still need to test for reserved words before identifiers but at least you are assured the code which implements the matching is guaranteed to be correct.

Comment: Real parsers generally separate lexing and parsing. The lexer detects tokens using a regexp, then the parser determines which tokens are language keywords.

Comment: In your design, you can solve the problem by putting the `word in [...]` cases first, then test the regexp when it doesn't match any of those keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Simply move your first regex "Identifier" to the end

```
import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

tokens = []                               
sample_code = open("book.txt","r").read().split()

for word in sample_code:
    
    if re.match("([1-9][0-9]*)|0", word):
        if word[len(word) - 1] == ';': 
            tokens.append([word[:-1], "is Num Constant"])
            tokens.append([';', 'is a Semi-colon'])
        else: 
            tokens.append([word, "is a Num Constant"])
    
    elif word in ['str', 'int', 'bool','float','char']: 
        tokens.append([word, 'is a Datatype'])
    
    elif word in '><!*-/+%=':
        tokens.append([word, "is an Operator"])
    

    elif word in ['if','for','break','elif','else','while','then','call','do',
    'endwhile', 'return','void','static','case','throw','private', 'public']:
        tokens.append([word, "is a Reserved Word"])

    elif re.match("[a-zA-Z]+", word):
        if word[len(word) - 1] == ';':
            tokens.append([word[:-1], "is an Identifier"])
            tokens.append([';', 'is a Semi-colon'])
        else:
            tokens.append([word, "is an Identifier"])

tokens = np.array(tokens)
tokens = pd.DataFrame(tokens, columns=['Token','Token_Type'])
# tokens.to_excel('tokens.xlsx', index=False)
print(tokens)
```

The output looks like this:

[image]